# "Private Key is Missing" using client certificate; used to work fine

Tags: paw-app

I haven't used Paw in a while. But now requests, which have a client certificate (with private key) in pasted PEM format, no longer work.

An existing request saved that I have used many times before will work once; but the moment I click on Options -> SSL Client Certificate, it immediately displays "Private Key is Missing" and the request will not even attempt, even though I didn't change anything.

What's going on? This was working for well over a year.

Comment: did you ever sort this out?